# Ошибка после установки kubuntu 18

Tags: git, ssh

Подскажите, после установки kubuntu 18 получаю

```
# git clone git@bitbucket.org:site.git
Cloning into 'site'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

В наличии имею `.ppk` и `.pem` файлы

> git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)

Как лечить?

Comment: В папке /~/userlogin/ssh/*.* запрещена запись файлов и он не может прочитать дефаулт настройки сессии ssh.

Comment: PEM — это сертификат доступа, а PPK 
 — действительно ключ, который вам нужен, но он от PuTTY https://askubuntu.com/a/818932/503251 (@NewView "блещет" знаниями)

Comment: @0andriy, ник верный, первый char объясняет суть собеседника :)